# Jumping to subsections of code in Python?

Tags: python, goto

I know everybody hates people who ask about anything related to goto, but here's my issue:
I'm an absolute beginner to coding, so I'm making little practice programs my 11 year old brother comes up with the ideas for. Here's a program where you can choose an item, and it'll take money from an account.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Acc = 30
print("$1 products: Pepsi, Water, Coke, Sprite")
print("$2 products: Chips, Cookies, Skittles, Twix")
print("$3 products: Amp, Monster, Red Bull, Rockstar")
L1 = ('Pepsi', 'Water', 'Coke', 'Sprite')
L2 = ('Chips', 'Cookies', 'Skittles', 'Twix')
L3 = ('Amp', 'Monster', 'Red Bull', 'Rockstar')
sel = raw_input("Please enter a product: ")
if sel in L1:
    print("$1 has been removed from your account.")
    Acc = Acc-1
    print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
if sel in L2:
    print("$2 has been removed from your account.")
    Acc = Acc-2
    print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
if sel in L3:
    print("$3 has been removed from your account.")
    Acc = Acc-3
    print("You now have $"), (Acc), ("left in your account")
```

I'd like to be able to jump from the end of an If statement to the point right before the user input section. Is there any way to do this in Python? Thanks in advance.(:

Comment: Hi, please next time put your code directly into the question, and use the "{}" button to format it :).

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is embed your statements into a `while` loop, and exit when a special value  (or not accepted) is given. Also, if the item you take can only be in 1 list, you should you `elif` statements, so when a true value is found, it exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Acc = 30
print("$1 products: Pepsi, Water, Coke, Sprite")
print("$2 products: Chips, Cookies, Skittles, Twix")
print("$3 products: Amp, Monster, Red Bull, Rockstar")
L1 = ('Pepsi', 'Water', 'Coke', 'Sprite')
L2 = ('Chips', 'Cookies', 'Skittles', 'Twix')
L3 = ('Amp', 'Monster', 'Red Bull', 'Rockstar')
while True:
    sel = raw_input("Please enter a product: ")
    if sel in L1:
        print("$1 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-1
        print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
    elif sel in L2:
        print("$2 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-2
        print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
    elif sel in L3:
        print("$3 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-3
        print("You now have $"), (Acc), ("left in your account")
    elif sel == "exit":
        break
```

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with this per se, I would advise staying away from `break` statements. Rather, assign `select = True` and do a `while select` and an `if sel == 'exit': select = False`

Comment: And I, on the other hand, fully endorse the use of `break` for breaking out of a `while` loop.  I write code like that all the time, and a `while True:` combined with a `break` to get out is a common idiom in Python.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is commonly achieved with a loop surrounding everything after the line that takes user input. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Acc = 30
print("$1 products: Pepsi, Water, Coke, Sprite")
print("$2 products: Chips, Cookies, Skittles, Twix")
print("$3 products: Amp, Monster, Red Bull, Rockstar")
L1 = ('Pepsi', 'Water', 'Coke', 'Sprite')
L2 = ('Chips', 'Cookies', 'Skittles', 'Twix')
L3 = ('Amp', 'Monster', 'Red Bull', 'Rockstar')
while True:
    sel = raw_input("Please enter a product: ")
    if sel == 'exit':
        break
    if sel in L1:
        print("$1 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-1
        print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
    if sel in L2:
        print("$2 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-2
        print("You now have $") (Acc), ("left in your account")
    if sel in L3:
        print("$3 has been removed from your account.")
        Acc = Acc-3
        print("You now have $"), (Acc), ("left in your account")
```

Comment: Okay, new question. I want the boolean to change to false when acc = 0. How hard would that be to do? Sorry, I'm still learning as I go.

Answer (score 1):

You can save typing all the items twice with this trick

```
L1 = ('Pepsi', 'Water', 'Coke', 'Sprite')
L2 = ('Chips', 'Cookies', 'Skittles', 'Twix')
L3 = ('Amp', 'Monster', 'Red Bull', 'Rockstar')
print("$1 products:", ", ".join(L1))
print("$2 products:", ", ".join(L2))
print("$3 products:", ", ".join(L3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd generally use a loop for that:

```
foo = 42
# … other setup …
while True:
    sel = raw_input(…)
    if sel == "foo":
        do_stuff()
    # … etc …
```